# Import module with older AGP and kotlin versions

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I created a new application that uses a local library. Both of them uses AGP 7.3.0 and kotlin version 1.7.10. My Android Studio (Hedgehog) is configured to use openjdk-17.0.2

I need to import an old library, written using AGP 4.0.2 and kotlin version 1.4.31.

Everytime that I run `./gradlew clean build`, I got these errors:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':my_project:compileProfileAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':my_project:profileCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :oldmodule.
     Required by:
         project :my_project
      > No matching variant of project :oldmodule was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.an
droid.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'profile', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform
.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'debugApiElements' capability android:oldmodule:unspecified declares an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.bu
ild.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer need
ed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'profile'
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' capability android:oldmodule:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.and
roid.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer need
ed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'profile'
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements' capability android:oldmodule:unspecified declares an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.
build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer ne
eded a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'profile'
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' capability android:oldmodule:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.a
ndroid.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer ne
eded a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'profile'
```

I'm importing using

`build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":oldmodule")
}
```

`settings.gradle`

```
include ":oldmodule"
project(":oldmodule").projectDir = new File("path/to/oldmodule/app/folder")
```

I don't know if makes any difference, but my project use `dataBinding` and I'm applying `kotlin-kapt`. All projects have

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 //1.8 in oldmodule
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Is it possible to import that library, or these versions are incompatible?

Comment: If you have different versions of Kotlin, you will have a problem importing the library. You can upgrade the Kotlin compiler version in the library to match the one in the application.